# PingFederate Administrative API

Tags: networking, pingfederate

Can I access PingFederate Administrative API outside the server? Currently I have access to the API using the localhost:9999 URL, but I need to be able to access it outside the server. I tried using the :9999 URL but to no avail.

Is there any config that I need to change? I'm able to ping the IP Address of the PingFederate server from my machine because we are on the same VPN. PORT 9999 is also opened for our connection but still can't access.

I'm trying to read the ff documentations but I can't find anything that could help my case.

https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf83/index.shtml#adminGuide/concept/configuringAccessToTheAdministrativeApi.html

https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/index.shtml#concept_accountManagement.html#concept_accountManagement

Comment: Does the server have more than one IP address? Are you trying to contact using a "short" name, or FQDN? Does `nslookup` return the expected IP address that is accessible? I ask these, because there is **nothing** within PingFederate itself that blocks access from an external address. I would suggest trying to use `openssl s_client -connect server.fqdn.com:9999` as a test, both from the server itself, as well as your external machine for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was indeed an issue within the security of our VPC. I was able to access the server now outside the server.